# Dynamically adjust font size by pure javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a code similar to this:

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.style.width = '200px';
a.style.fontSize = fontSize(a.offsetWidth, 5);
a.innerHTML = 'Example';
document.body.appendChild(a);

function fontSize(reference, factor){
  return (reference*factor)/100 + 'px';
}
```

However when I run it, the element font size appears to be 0px. The `console.log` returns expected value tho.

Similar code works on an javascript object that I tried:

```
var Object = function(target){
  var default = {
    fontSize: fontSize(target.clientWidth, 5);
  }
}
```

[jsFiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/frp3hdcy/)

What did I do wrong?

Comment: Do you have any browser restrictions?

Comment: @SirMcPotato not that I know of. it works on the second code example but not on the first code example in the same sheet of code.

Comment: Why wouldn't you use a css class for this?

Comment: @Shilly I am a beginner and am practicing to build a module and trying to use as little dependencies as possible.

Comment: You are asking your browser for the `offsetWidth` of a div having no content and having no `parentNode`. What width would you expect this node to have if not `0`? And `(0*5)/100 + 'px' === '0px'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The HTMLElement.offsetWidth read-only property returns the layout width of an element. Typically, an element's offsetWidth is a measurement which includes the element borders, the element horizontal padding, the element vertical scrollbar (if present, if rendered) and the element CSS width.

Your newly created `div` element has not been appended to the document when you try to read the `offsetWidth`, consequently it has a layout width of `0` so you end up with a font-size of `0px`.

You need to put the div in the document before you measure how much space it takes up in the document.

Alternatively, you need to use a value other than `offsetWidth` (such as `style.width`.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic is good, but you should append your element to the DOM **before** trying to retrieve its size:

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.style.width = '200px';
a.innerHTML = 'Example';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style.fontSize = fontSize(a.offsetWidth, 5);

function fontSize(reference, factor) {
  return (reference * factor) / 100 + 'px';
}
```

### [Forked your Fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/38gf46co/)

Comment: Dividing by 100 doesn't make it tiny. You could multiply it by 1000 and still end up with zero.

Answer (score 0):

Just put `a.style.fontSize = fontSize(a.offsetWidth, 5);` after `document.body.appendChild(a);`.

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.style.width = '200px';
a.innerHTML = 'Example';
document.body.appendChild(a);

a.style.fontSize = fontSize(a.offsetWidth, 5); // <--- Move here

function fontSize(reference, factor){
  return (reference*factor)/100 + 'px';
}
```

In fact, there's CSS properties you can't edit while the element is not added to the DOM. Font-size is one of them.

Answer (score 0):

You need to append "a" to document first before you calculate its offsetWidth.

Refer - http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_element_offsetwidth.asp

```
var a = document.createElement('div');
a.style.width = '200px';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.style.fontSize = fontSize(a.offsetWidth, 5);
a.innerHTML = 'Example';


function fontSize(reference, factor){
  return (reference*factor)/100 + 'px';
}
```